# string to timestamp

Tags: php, javascript, python, datetime, timestamp

I have this date time stuff, that needs to be converted to timestamp. I am looking for conversions in 3 states, with Javascript, Python and PHP. My main problem is that I am not able to catch what format this string is in: `2013-07-29T18:54:09.743390-08:00`
Also, can anybody please share what format this is?

Answer (score 2):

A generic way to do this with PHP is strtotime()
In Javascript, you can try to

```
var d=new Date("your datetime here");
```

Although, I am not 100% sure of the result you will get with the format you have. Maybe someone else can help out about that.
As for Python, someone else should probably help you, as I am not familiar. Or you could google "python equivalent to php strtotime", or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
print strtotime('2013-07-29T18:54:09.743390-08:00');
```

result:

```
1375152849
```

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> dateString = "02/24/2012"
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString,"%m/%d/%Y").timetuple())
1330034400.0
```

PHP:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('02/24/2012');    
print $timestamp.PHP_EOL; #OUTPUT 1330034400
```

Javascript:

```
var date = new Date('2012-02-24')
date.getTime()/100
```